# Parse.com REST API - How to Assign user Id to each installation

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I am developing an IONIC2 app and working with Parse's REST API.

My issue is that I want to assign a userID to the current installation in `Installation` class.

**The flow:**

1. The user opens the app, a new installation object is created in the `installation` class by assigning the following fields:

   ```
     let deviceInfo = {
       "deviceToken":deviceToken,
       "installationId":uuid,
       "deviceModel":model,
       "deviceVersion":version,
       "appName":"app",
       "appVersion":"1.0.0",
       "channels": [
         "global"
       ]
     };
   ```
2. Once the user clicks on the sign-up button, a session object is created in the `session` class and the `installationId` is by default set to (undefined); however, a userId is assigned to that newly created session object.

**My Question:**

How can I assign the userID of the newly registered user in `Installation` class, *like it was made automatically in the `session` class*?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**
Did you try it with cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_Installation", function(request, response) {
    var createdAt = request.object.get("createdAt");
    var updatedAt = request.object.get("updatedAt");
    if (createdAt.getTime() == updatedAt.getTime()) {
      //object didnt exist before, so save the User (pointer to _User class)
      request.object.set("user_id", request.user);
      response.success();
    };
});
```

Comment: I know, the code you provided works only for iOS and Android, I haven't found a way to do the same in JS or REST API, and that's my question!

Comment: you can do it in cloud code too... when the Installation class gets saved for first time you just save the ID of the user who saved it... and you save yourself a network request

Comment: That's what I was doing now, but I have some issues to set the userID pointer as I've tried to do the following, but it didn't work:         object.set("userID", {__type: "Pointer", className: "User", objectId: userID});